# How to use jQuery to set min-height the same as window

Tags: jquery, html, css

How would I set the css min-height of the .inner-wrap div to match the window height using jQuery? I need it to run on document load and window resize too?

```
$(window).resize(function() {

$('.inner-wrap').height ( $(window).height() );

});
```

Comment: yes you have to... so `$(window).resize(function() {

$('.inner-wrap').height ( $(window).height() );

}).resize();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method like so:

```
$('.inner-wrap').css("height", $(window).height() + "px" );
```

or min-height:

```
$('.inner-wrap').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px" );
```

When you set css each time you resize the window, it can cause a performance issue. therefore, use a little trick:

```
// short for $(document).ready()
$(function() {
    var timer;

    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.inner-wrap').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px" );
        }, 40);
    }).resize();
});
```

What this code does exactly;

As soon as the document loads, it starts adding all the functions. It creates an empty variable "timer" which will later be used as a timeout wrapper function. It then adds the resize event to the window and immediately calls it on the window object (`...resize();`) which causes the function to run right at the beginning.
Within the function there is a timeout handling which ensures the css is only applied once the user stops resizing the window for a very short time. you can play with the integer of 40 (ms). hope that helps

Comment: That has fixed it! You've just fixed the off-canvas nav bug in Foundation 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.inner-wrap').css("min-height", $(window).height() + "px");
```